# Transcribing for-loop in one line to staircase for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop, generator-expression

My task is to transcribe one line for-loop:

```
mystr = '12345'
result = sum(int(i) for i in mystr)
print(result)
```

into staircase for-loop with indentations.

The first one

```
result = sum(int(i) for i in mystr)
```

works just fine.
This is what I tried to do and it didn't work.
Can anyone help, please?

```
mystr = "12345"
for i in str:
    result = sum(int(i))
print(result)
```

Comment: You're only summing one digit and assigning that to the result. You need to update result as well.  Use `result += sum(int(i))`

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful as I was banging my head on the wall trying to make the sum function work. I appreciate it

Comment: No problem NurlanK. Glad you got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
mystr = '12345'
result = 0
for i in mystr:
    result += int(i)
print(result)
```

You have to have initial integer value because you're going to add integers together that's why I used `result = 0`.